# Docker Desktop Bad Gateway (502)

Tags: docker

I am running Sitecore 10.2 XM in Docker Desktop. It has no issues loading the site in a browser on my laptop but throws a bad gateway error in a VM that has nested virtualization. It used to run fine in the VM until a Docker Desktop upgrade I believe. I do not see any errors on docker compose up as all the Containers create. When I try to access my site at cm.mysite.localhost it gives an all blank page with "Bad Gateway" in text. Of note:

- Windows Firewall is not enabled
- I am using WSL2 with Docker Compose V2 and tested with a Hyper-V backend and receive the same error
- The VM has 4 Cores and 16GB of RAM with a 24GB Swap file
- Host file entries added by Docker Desktop are as follows:

```
10.23.124.5 host.docker.internal
10.23.124.5 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs for CM?

Comment: 2023-06-05 20:49:56 2936 20:49:27 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
2023-06-05 20:49:56 2124 20:49:28 ERROR Unhandled exception detected. The ASP.NET worker process will be terminated. 
2023-06-05 20:49:56 Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException
2023-06-05 20:49:56 Message: Could not load file or assembly 
This one stands out: 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: I have been wondering if its some sort of cert issue

Comment: I would suggest checking if the System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll is deployed to CM.

Comment: Will take a 2nd look. It should be

Comment: What happens if you copy your bin files from a working environment to your cm instance?

Comment: The odd thing is the files work on all of our local laptops... these are the same files from our repo and the containers are running/images created as expected/bins match. Its only when running in the VM that we see a bad gateway... same exact files, setup, etc. Wondering if the VM needs more power as its 16GB and has a 24GB paging file set

Comment: It can be a Memory issue as well, we faced this type of issue once.

Comment: Thanks, will test increasing it

Comment: Increasing power did not resolve it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Were you able to confirm the DLL is available in the bin directory? That seems the most likely issue. It could be reading that file from GAC on your local machine, but not have it available on the VM.

Comment: It has the following in the BIN: system.security.cryptography.xml.dll

Comment: Is the correct version of the DLL deployed? It should be File Version: 4.6.265.15.6. If any other version is deployed it will give the exact error thatyou have described.

Comment: its 7.0.22.51805 from CM container. How/where do I get the correct version? We all have the same setup but others have the version you mentioned... I am wondering if I need to blow away my images/it is stored there.

Comment: An image is immutable, so if you are using same image as others you would have exact same files. Given you have different version, I'm guessing you are using different image or tag of same image. What image are you using? Have you customised it? If so look at the build process. What version is showing in your solution? Could multiple versions be referenced in project?

Comment: Its pulled fresh from the same source control. Base image is 10.2-ltsc2019. No customizations as these are the default Sitecore images. Our solution layers on top of it. Will check if the DLL is overwriting as we are applying the 10.2.1 hotfix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussions in the comments, it seems the reason for the bad gateway error is an incorrect version of `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml`.

Sitecore versions 9.3-10.3 all ship with `File Version: 4.6.26515.6`

If you take a healthy sitecore instance and copy in the latest version of the `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` DLL into the bin folder, you will get the following error:

```
26112 07:53:47 ERROR Unhandled exception detected. The ASP.NET worker process will be terminated. 
Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source: Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing
```

This is stipulating that the assembly has been found, but is not the correct version. Note: `Version: 4.0.1.0` relates to `File Version: 4.6.26515.6`

You will also see the error is showing "The ASP.NET worker process will be terminated". Which explains why there is nothing to map through to in Docker Desktop.

You mention in your comments that there are:

> No customizations as these are the default Sitecore images

Yet, you also say:

> Our solution layers on top of it

By layering your solution over the top of the Sitecore images, you are in turn creating a custom image. Due to the fact that Sitecore ships with version `4.6.26515.6` and you have identified version `7.0.22.51805` in the deployed code, therefore your solution must be layering the new DLL over the top.

Please review your solutions nuget packages and make sure that all references point to the same version `4.6.26515.6`.

Comment: What is odd is that we all get from the same repo and no one else has this issue. I am the only one to pull fresh images so wondering if the latest Sitecore images have a file issue

Comment: That should be straight forward to check - set cm image in docker-compose file to use the latest sitecore version. Comment/remove any volume mounts. Spin up the environment and exec in via docker desktop and review file. Or use "docker cp" command to copy out the file to check the version.

Comment: Thanks Dan and to all. We had different versions of the dll that likely came over from a nuget package. Once resolved, it loads as expected.

Comment: No problem - glad you got it working

Comment: I experienced the issue by using a generic docker image version (10.2-ltsc2019). I updated to 10.2.0-ltsc2019 instead of dealing with the web.config.